# Boto Scan Filterexpression : Invalid type for parameter

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to use the following code, but I am unable to get it to work. It keeps giving me an error message about the filter expression being the incorrect type, even though I am doing exactly what is done in [the documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.scan). What can I do to fix this?

```html
def EndpointDeleted(event):
    endpoint = event['Attributes']['EndpointArn']
    if('EndpointArn' in event['Attributes']):
        client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
        response = client.scan(
            TableName='sniffergps-mobilehub-812282467-Users',
            Select='ALL_ATTRIBUTES',
            FilterExpression=Attr('Endpoints').contains(endpoint)
        )
        return response
```

But I get an error saying that the filter expression is the incorrect type. I have the following import messages: 
`import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Attr`

Error message:

```html
{
  "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter FilterExpression, value: <boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Contains object at 0x7fdca25e0b38>, type: <class 'boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Contains'>, valid types: <class 'str'>",
  "errorType": "ParamValidationError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      13,
      "lambda_handler",
      "return EndpointDeleted(event)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      24,
      "EndpointDeleted",
      "FilterExpression=Attr('Endpoints').contains(endpoint)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
      312,
      "_api_call",
      "return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
      575,
      "_make_api_call",
      "api_params, operation_model, context=request_context)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
      630,
      "_convert_to_request_dict",
      "api_params, operation_model)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/validate.py",
      291,
      "serialize_to_request",
      "raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Note the difference in syntax between the Boto3 DynamoDB [Client](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#client), and the Table [Resource](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#table).

The `FilterExpression` parameter for DynamoDB client expects a string.

The method you are using to set the `FilterExpression` parameter looks like the way you would use a DynamoDB.Table resource.

Comment: This answer is incomplete. *How* would one change the syntax from the table one to the one accepted by the client?